# Put date modified field of the MP3 file into it's ID3 tag

Tags: mp3, date, tags, id3

Is there a quick way to do what title says? I tried MP3Tag but I don't think it's possible at all. Google search didn't help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the Date Modified value to the ID3 tag's DATE value, with **Tag - Tag** function in Mp3Tag. (See screenshot)

[image]